# Failed Prop Type Error in Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to get Fine Uploader React to work but keep running into issues.

I'm getting the following errors:
[image]

Here's the URL: http://fineuploader.azurewebsites.net/

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded the source on to my computer from https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader
2. I then `npm install`ed `react-fine-uploader` and `fine-uploader` as per instructions
3. I ran `webpack` to transpile and bundle the code
4. Added an entry point and `index.html`
5. Finally, I simply published the app to a new Azure app/website

Any idea what's causing the issue?

P.S. My goal is to use Fine Uploader to upload files to Azure Blob Storage. At this point, I'm simply trying to get Fine Uploader going. I do realize that I'll have to enter a few pieces of information about my blog storage endpoint, etc. but I don't think this error is related to any of that.

Comment: you istantiated an uploader to pass as props to the gallery element? p.s. you will need fine-uploader-wrappers too

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not clear as to what I need to do. I did `npm install fine-uploader-wrappers` as per your suggestion. I thought I could simply drop the `Gallery` component into my entry point. Could you please be more specific as to what I need to do get this going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Gallery (and every higher level component of that library) needs an "uploader" props as explained in the section https://github.com/FineUploader/react-fine-uploader#high-level-components

An uploader is one of the 3 classes avaiable in the fine-uploader-wrappers package https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader-wrappers#wrapper-classes
those are for upload to

1. Aws s3
2. Azure
3. or your enpoint

The uploader class need all the configuration endpoint, credentials, custom configuration, etc... (you can find a comprehensive list here in the api section https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html)

An example for s3 direct upload would be something like:

```
const uploader = new FineUploaderS3({
    options: {
        request: {
            endpoint: "http://fineuploadertest.s3.amazonaws.com",
            accessKey: "AKIAIXVR6TANOGNBGANQ"
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: "/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint.php"
        }
    }
})
```

and use that uploader in a gallery

```
 <Gallery uploader={ uploader } />
```

There are many usefull option for customization: callbacks, onEventHandler, etc you can find them all in the docs of fineuploader

**Edit**: if im not mistaken `react-transition-group` is necessary even if it's not listed anywhere in the docs...